Collect records with time difference between a database column and current time on MSSQL database using Spring Boot Specification
I need to get the records with time diff of 60 minutes between a column in the database and the current time. I am using the below specification for the same on MSSQL database using Spring Boot.
Expression<Long> differenceInHours = criteriaBuilder.function("DATEDIFF", Long.class, criteriaBuilder.literal(ChronoUnit.MINUTES), criteriaBuilder.literal(localDateTime), root.get("targetTime"));
                        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThan(differenceInHours, 60));

In this case, localDateTime is the current timestamp and targetTime is the column in the database.
I am getting the below error.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmLiteral cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmDurationUnit (org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmLiteral and org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmDurationUnit are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.TimestampdiffFunction$TimestampdiffFunctionReturnTypeResolver.resolveFunctionReturnType(TimestampdiffFunction.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.SelfRenderingSqmFunction.resolveResultType(SelfRenderingSqmFunction.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.SelfRenderingSqmFunction.convertToSqlAst(SelfRenderingSqmFunction.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitFunction(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:6138)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitFunction(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmFunction.accept(SqmFunction.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitComparisonPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7436)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitComparisonPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.accept(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitJunctionPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:7096)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitJunctionPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmJunctionPredicate.accept(SqmJunctionPredicate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitWhereClause(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2482)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2059)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmQuerySpec.accept(SqmQuerySpec.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.spi.BaseSemanticQueryWalker.visitQueryPart(BaseSemanticQueryWalker.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQueryPart(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1913)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1598)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement.accept(SqmSelectStatement.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.translate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:441)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:352)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)

Any ideas on how to address this ?

have you fixed the issue?
